# Updating Attribute variables in Vertex Shader(glVertexAttrib3f) working as glVertex

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, geometry-shader

I am having trouble using Attribute variables for getting a value into vertex shader. I want to provide the geometry shader with one of the points from the previous primitive(line) for some calculation. I am providing this point using a vec3 attribute variable(Ppoint) in to vertex shader and then to geometry shader using a out variable in vertex shader and a in variable in geometry shader(pointPass).

The problem is when I am updating the attribute variable in the glBegin()/glEnd() block while drawing the lines the values in glVertexAttrib3f are taken as vertices and a line is also rendered to those points. This causes some extra lines to be displayed and all the geometry shader functionality is disturbed.

Here is my code for all the shaders and my opengl program to draw the lines.

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 compatibility
out vec3 pointPass;
attribute vec3 Ppoint;
void main()
{ 
    pointPass = Ppoint;
    gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
}
```

Geometry Shader

```
#version 330 compatibility
in vec3 pointPass[]; 
out vec4 colorFrag; 
layout(lines) in;
// 100 vertices are not actually required specified more for trial
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=100) out;

vec3 getA(vec3 axis){ 
    vec3 a; 
    a.x = 1.0;
    a.y = 1.0; 
    a.z = -(axis.x + axis.y)/axis.z; 
    a = normalize(a); 
    return a;
}
vec3 getB(vec3 axis, vec3 a){ 
    vec3 b;
    b.x = (a.y*axis.z - a.z*axis.y);
    b.y = (a.z*axis.x - a.x*axis.z);
    b.z = (a.x*axis.y - a.y*axis.x );
    b = normalize(b);
    return b;
}

void main()
{ 
    vec3 axis0, axis1, v0, v1, v2; 
    float radius = 0.5;
    float rotation = 0.0f;
    float pi = 3.1416; 
    int numPoints = 15;
    vec3 p1, p2, p3, p4;
    int count = 0, i;
    float increment = 2*pi/numPoints;
    v0 = pointPass[0];
    v1 = gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    v2 = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz;

    axis1 = v1 - v2;
    axis1 = normalize(axis1);
    vec3 a1 = getA(axis1);
    vec3 b1 = getB(axis1, a1);

    axis0 = v0-v2;
    axis0 = normalize(axis0);
    vec3 a0 = getA(axis0);
    vec3 b0 = getB(axis0, a0);

    // Rotation with theta
    for(rotation = 0; rotation<=2*pi; rotation+=increment){

    p1 = v1 + radius*cos(rotation)*a0 + radius*sin(rotation)*b0; 
    p2 = v1 + radius*cos(rotation + increment)*a0 + radius*sin (rotation + increment)*b0;
    p3 = v2 + radius*cos(rotation)*a1 + radius*sin(rotation)*b1; 
    p4 = v2 + radius*cos(rotation + increment)*a1 + radius*sin(rotation + increment)*b1;
    // FIRST Triangle 
    // FIRST vertex 
    gl_Position = (gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*vec4(p3,1.0) );
    EmitVertex(); 
    // SECOND vertex
    gl_Position = (gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*vec4(p1, 1.0) ); 
    EmitVertex();
    // THIRD vertex
    gl_Position = (gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*vec4(p4, 1.0) );
    EmitVertex();
    // SECOND Triangle
    // FIRST vertex 
    gl_Position = (gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*vec4(p2, 1.0) ); 
    EmitVertex();

    }
    EndPrimitive(); 
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 compatibility
in vec4 colorFrag;
void main()
{ 
    gl_FragColor = colorFrag;
}
```

OpenGL program for drawing lines

```
// vPoints is a std::vector of 3d vector class created by me.
void drawLines(){
     float angle =0.0f;
     int numLines = 30;
     int count = 0;
     float disp = 0.30f;
     float radius_x = 5.0;
     float radius_y = 5.0;
     vPoints.resize(numLines+2);
    // Loop around in a circle and specify even points along the spiral
    float increment = (float)(2*GL_PI/numLines);
    for(angle = 0.0f; angle < (2.0f*GL_PI); angle += increment)
    {   
        // Calculate x and y position of the next vertex
        float x1 = radius_x*sin(angle);
        float y1 = radius_y*cos(angle);
        float z1 = count*disp;
        vPoints[count].SetVector(x1, y1, z1);
        count ++;
    }

    // Drawing only first two line segments for testing
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        int pointPassLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "Ppoint");
      // This is also considered as a vertex and a line is drawn from this point to  vPoints[1]
        glVertexAttrib3f(pointPassLocation, vPoints[0].GetX(), vPoints[0].GetY(), vPoints[0].GetZ());

        glVertex3d(vPoints[1].GetX(), vPoints[1].GetY(), vPoints[1].GetZ());
        glVertex3d(vPoints[2].GetX(), vPoints[2].GetY(), vPoints[2].GetZ());
        // Again this is also considered as a point and a line is drawn from vPoints[2] to this point.
        glVertexAttrib3f(pointPassLocation, vPoints[1].GetX(), vPoints[1].GetY(), vPoints[1].GetZ());

        glVertex3d(vPoints[2].GetX(), vPoints[2].GetY(), vPoints[2].GetZ());
        glVertex3d(vPoints[3].GetX(), vPoints[3].GetY(), vPoints[3].GetZ());
    glEnd();
}
```

So instead of 2 lines which I wanted to draw from vPoints[1] to vPoints[2] and vPoints[2] to vPoints[3], I am getting 3 lines with 6 vertices considering the two glVertexAttrib3f statements as vertices.

Am I doing it correct, or is there a better way or another way to do this.

Comment: So is your problem that you want two lines to be drawn but three are being drawn instead? Or does your code work and you just want to know if there is a better way to accomplish what you are doing?

Comment: @bwroga code is not supposed to draw more than two lines but it is drawing. and also I want to know it there is a better way.

Comment: Can you explain what your geometry shader is supposed to do?

Comment: @AdityaG the better way would be to use VBOs and `glVertexAttribPointer` instead.

Comment: @bwroga I am trying to draw cylinders around a line. I could achieve it. But when I am trying to draw properly connected cylinders around a line strip I needed the previous vertex to orient the face of the cylinder properly. so I need to pass the previous vertex to the shader.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz  thank you for your suggestion .. I solved it using VBO approach.

Comment: Then post your solution as an answer